# IdentityUserRole Table column duplicated and can't drop primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I have a issue with my UserRole table I renamed my tables by the following definition

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
 {
    builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").HasKey<Int32>(r => r.Id);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(r => new{ r.IDNumber, r.UserName});
    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").HasKey<string>(r => r.UserName);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
 }
```

I have not defined a custom UserRole class so in this case am just using IdentityUserRole. However, when I look at my UserRole table there is `RoleId`and `IdentityRole_Id` with similar values

[image]

Using my UserManager

```
 IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(regUser.Id, role.Name);
```

It only removes the `IdentityRole_Id` and `IdentityUser_UserName` entities. I can't figure out a way to remove the `RoleId` and `UserId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `base.OnModelCreating(builder);` before your code which will setup relations for AspNetIdentity

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    // Add this line
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").HasKey<Int32>(r => r.Id);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin").HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
    builder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User").HasKey(r => new{ r.IDNumber, r.UserName});
    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User").HasKey<string>(r => r.UserName);
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole").HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```